# Bad pagenumber display in head and footline

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm just writing my thesis in Latex and I am having a problem with the pagenumber display.

I want the **headline** to contain chapternumber, chaptername and pagenumber. The footline should be empty.
An alternative would be that the pagenumber is displayed in the lower right corner of the page (then not in the headline).
Anways, my current situation is that the pagenumber IS displayed in the headline together with the chapternumber and chaptername, but on the pages that contain the beginning of a new \section the pagenumber is displayed in the middle of the footline and the headline is totally empty.
Now what can I do so that the pagenumber is either:
• Displayed on the right of the headline or
• Not at all (on the pages that contain a new \section or \chapter?

The document is supposed to be onesided. Here is my header of the tex-file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,toc=listofnumbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, twoside=false, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, marginparwidth=0pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color} %Farbe im Allgemeinen
%\usepackage{colortbl} % Für farbig hinterlegte Zellen in Tabellen
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Um Umgebung \wrapfigure benutzen zu können 
\usepackage{amsmath} %Für Equation-Umgebung
\usepackage{amssymb} %Für verschiedene Mathesymbole
\usepackage{nicefrac} %ermöglicht Brüche mit Schrägstrichdarstellung
\usepackage{array} %Für Paragraph-Spalten in Tabular-Umgebung
\usepackage{textcomp} %Für Pfeildarstellungen im Text
\usepackage{picins} % Textumflossene Bilder 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, figurename=Abb., tablename=Tab.]{caption} %Umbenennung der Bild- und Tabellenunterschriften in Abkürzungen
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\restylefloat{figure} % Damit Package "Float" wirksam wird
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup{font={small}}
\usepackage[pdftex]{rotating} %Objekte können rotiert werden
\usepackage{setspace} %ermöglicht das Einstellen des Zeilenabstands
\onehalfspacing  %Stellt auf 1,5fachen Zeilenabstand ein
\graphicspath{{Bilder_Diplomarbeit/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Um Kopfzeilen editieren zu können

%Abstand zwischen einzelnen Absätzen und kein Zeileneinzug am Anfang
\parindent=0pt                  % Setzt den Zeileneinzug
\parskip=\smallskipamount       % Setzt den Freiraum zwischen zwei Absaetzen
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.17}

%Farbdefinitionen
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean `\chapter`, not `\section`, correct?

Answer (score 3):

`scrbook` defines `\titlepagestyle`, `\partpagestyle`, `\chapterpagestyle`, and `\indexpagestyle`. It execute `\thispagestyle\chapterpagestyle` when you start a new chapter. So simply `\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}` to clean up your chapter-page.

If somehow you change your mind in the future, you may define your own page style using, for instance, `fancyhdr` in your preamble.